# Perl: comparing elements from a regex result

Tags: regex, perl, enums

So i have a data file that contains a couple of lines that I am using for testing purposes. The data file contains this:

```
typedef enum A
{
enum A = 0;
enum B = 1;
}
A;

typedef enum B
{
enum A = 1;
enum B = 2;
}
B;
```

My code consists of this:

```
open(DATA, "<file.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

while(<DATA>){
   print if /^(.*)(enum)(.*)$/;
}
```

I want to compare the values of A and A in each typedef and print an error suggesting compile error. How can i store these regex search results as variables?

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to compare to what? What compile error?

Answer (score 0):

Just store the values returned from the match in list context (see [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop) for details):

Keep a hash of declared variable names, report the error if an already declared name appears again:

```
my %declared;
while (<DATA>) {
    if (my ($name) = /\b enum \s+ (\w+)/x) {
           die "$name re-declared" if $declared{$name};
        $declared{$name} = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: open(DATA, "<file.txt") or die "Couldn't open file file.txt, $!";

while(<DATA>){
   if (/^(.*)(enum)(.*)$/)
   {
   print if /^(enum)(.*)$/;
   }

}
This is my editted code, if you run this with the above contents of the text file from my original post you will see that there is two declarations of a variable named A. I want to compare all the names of the variables and say that if there is two instances of the same name for a variable, then print a warning.